# What does INNER_SELECT - SELECT mean?

Tags: newrelic

In New Relic on the Monitoring > Database > Most time consuming I have a query named INNER_SELECT - SELECT. What does this mean?

Comment: any chance you're using Entity Framework in your app?

Answer (score 1):

It means you have multiple subqueries (or Inner queries/Nested queries) being made by your application and New Relic is timing them.

Comment: Is this a bad thing? Should I ignore this?

Comment: New Relic is just telling you what's happening.  So, from New Relic's point of you, it's neither good nor bad.